# Nestjs testing - service method returns data when it shouldn't

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I am writing a unit test which mocks the creation of a new user in the database. Inside the `user.service.add` method, I do a `findOne` call to check if the user exists in the db. In development, this works correctly, however, in the test - findOne returns data when it should not.

at least I don't think it should. Why is it returning data?

**my test**

```
const testUserUsername1 = faker.internet.userName();
const testUserEmail1 = faker.internet.email();
const testUserPassword1 = faker.internet.password();
const testUserName1 = `${faker.name.firstName()} ${faker.name.lastName()}`;

const testUserName2 = `${faker.name.firstName()} ${faker.name.lastName()}`;

// user test object
const testUser = new User(
  testUserName1,
  testUserEmail1,
  testUserPassword1,
  testUserUsername1,
);

describe('UserService', () => {
  let userService: UserService;
  let postService: PostService;
  let likeService: LikeService;
  let userRepository: Repository<User>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        UserService,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(User),
          useClass: Repository,
        },
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(User),
          // mocks of all the methods from the User Service
          useValue: {
            save: jest.fn(),
            create: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(testUser),
            find: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(testUsers),
            findOne: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(testUser),
            update: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(testUser),
            delete: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true),
          },
        },
        PostService,
        {
          provide: PostService,
          useClass: Repository,
        },
        LikeService,
        {
          provide: LikeService,
          useClass: Repository,
        },
      ],
    }).compile();
    userRepository = module.get<Repository<User>>(getRepositoryToken(User));
    userService = module.get<UserService>(UserService);
    postService = module.get<PostService>(PostService);
    likeService = module.get<LikeService>(LikeService);
  });

it('should be able to create a user', async () => {
    const tempUser = {
      name: testUserName1,
      email: testUserEmail1,
      username: testUserUsername1,
      password: testUserPassword1,
    }
    userRepository.findOne = jest.fn(() => tempUser.username);

    await userService.add(tempUser)
    expect(tempUser).toEqual(testUser);
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
});
```

**user.service.add**

```
  async add(userDto: Partial<UserCreateDTO>): Promise<UserDTO> {
    // get data from args
    const { name, password, username, email } = userDto;

    // check if the user exists in the db
    const userInDb = await this.userRepository.findOne({
      where: { username },
    });

    console.log('username: ', username)
    console.log('userInDb: ', userInDb)

    if (userInDb) {
      throw new HttpException('User already exists', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    // create new user 
    const user: User = await this.userRepository.create({
      name,
      password,
      username,
      email,
    });

    // save changes to database
    await this.userRepository.save(user);

    // return user object
    return toUserDto(user);
  }
```

**console.log output inside user.service.add**

```
   console.log src/user/user.service.ts:49
      username: Mayra_Rolfson53
    console.log src/user/user.service.ts:50
      userInDb: User {
        name: 'Albert Kuvalis',
        email: 'Martin_Jacobson@gmail.com',
        username: 'SQT_L6iGKzPVFPI',
        password: 'Mayra_Rolfson53'
      }
```

**error thrown**

```
    User already exists

      50 |     console.log('userInDb', userInDb)
      51 |     if (userInDb) {
    > 52 |       throw new HttpException('User already exists', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
         |             ^
      53 |     }
```

Comment: Don't you specifically define this behavior for the mock user repository?

```
findOne: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(testUser),
```

Comment: I guess I do don't I? lol. If I don't do that then I get `findOne is not a function`.. and what if I want to text findOne in another test after this but only in **this** case I want findOne to return nothing?

Comment: Ok, so the test behaves absolutely expected - findOne() does return the pre-defined user object every time it's called.

You probably need to alter the mock behavior to fit the needs of this particular test.
If this .fndOne() is only gonna be called once in the test, and you need it to return null, then do exactly that!

`findOne: jest.fn().mockResolvedVaue(null)`

Comment: ah that works too! I instead wrote an answer below with another solution and tagged u in it. U can post this answer as a solution as well!

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to add a return type when a user is **NOT** found in my findOne method

BEFORE

```
  async findOne(uid: string): Promise<User> {
    return await this.userRepository.findOne({
      relations: ['posts', 'comments'],
      where: { uid },
    });
  }
```

AFTER

```
  async findOne(uid: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
    return await this.userRepository.findOne({
      relations: ['posts', 'comments'],
      where: { uid },
    });
  }
```

now In my test I will expect `undefined` to be returned instead of `testUser` in my `findOne` mock

```
  it('should be able to create a user', async () => {
    const tempUser = {
      name: testUserName1,
      email: testUserEmail1,
      username: testUserUsername1,
      password: testUserPassword1,
    }
    userRepository.findOne = jest.fn(() => undefined);

    await userService.add(tempUser)
    expect(tempUser).toEqual(testUser);

  });
```

my test now passes however **I don't know if this is best practise** in TypeScript or Nest.js testing alltogether. If anyone has a better suggestions please feel free to post it!

thanks to @amakhrov  for the tip in the comments!